# WiX: Old versions don't disappear in Add/Remove Programs list

Tags: visual-studio, windows-services, wix

I have a Windows Service that I install and upgrade with WiX, and this works great (it's very fast!). The only problem is that if I upgrade from, say, 1.0 to 1.1, both copies still have entries in the Add/Remove Programs list.

So how can I make sure WiX removes its old/outdated entries in the Add/Remove Programs list when I perform an update?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a major upgrade. For example, use the MajorUpgrade element in WiX v3.5. http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/01/16/major-upgrades-now-easier-than-ever/

Comment: This worked perfectly... I even removed an old block of XML code that this tag replaced. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

An addendum to this - if the `RemoveFeatures` attribute of `MajorUpgrade` is included, and names specific features to remove from the previous install (but not all of the features), that will cause the previous entry to remain in Add/Remove programs. If `RemoveFeatures` is not included, all the features of the previous install will be removed, including the entry in Add/Remove programs.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly an answer to the question but ... the installer only looks at the first 3 groups of the version number, the 4th group is ignored. If the only difference in the version is in the 4th group then it looks the same to the installer so the old version may not be uninstalled.

1.2.3.0 will upgrade to 1.2.4.0 but 1.2.3.4 will not upgrade to 1.2.3.5 - it doesn't see the 4-5 change because it doesn't look there.

Comment: This is right! I have a process that rolls the 4th part of the version sequence based on my git commit count. I was testing install / uninstall without changing the first 3 digit parts, and it showed up twice. When I changed one of the other 3 numbers, the old version got uninstalled. Interesting.